# sybase cursors in a trigger

Tags: triggers, cursor, sap-ase

I am trying to use a cursor in a trigger on a sybase ASE 15.0.3 system running on Solaris. The purpose for this is that I want to know which column of a table is getting updated. This information I then save in an admin table for further lookups.

```
create trigger test_trigger on my_table for update as

set nocount on

/* declare cursor */
declare @colname varchar(64)

declare column_name cursor for 
    select syscolumns.name from syscolumns join sysobjects on (sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id) where sysobjects.name = 'my_table'

/* open the cursor */
open column_name

/* fetch the first row */
fetch column_name into @colname

/* now loop, processing all the rows
** @@sqlstatus = 0 means successful fetch
** @@sqlstatus = 1 means error on previous fetch
** @@sqlstatus = 2 means end of result set reached
*/
while (@@sqlstatus != 2)
begin    
    /* check for errors */
    if (@@sqlstatus = 1)
    begin
        print "Error in column_names cursor"
        return
    end

    /* now do the insert if colum was updaed  */
    if update(@colname)
    begin
        insert into my_save_table (login,tablename,field,action,pstamp) 
            select suser_name(),'my_table',@colname,'U',getdate() from inserted
    end

    /* fetch the next row */
    fetch column_name into @colname
end

/* close the cursor and return */
close column_name   
go
```

Unfortunately when trying to run this in isql I get the following error:

```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1:
 Server 'my_sybase_server', Procedure 'test_trigger', Line 34:
 Incorrect syntax near '@colname'.
```

I did some investigations and found out that line 34 means the following statement:

```
if update(@colname)
```

then I tried to just check on 1 column and replaced it by

```
if update(some_column_name)
```

That actually worked fine and I don't have any other idea how to fix that. It looks like the update() function somehow not allows to contain a variable. I did not find any additional information on the sybase books or anywhere else in google ect. Does anybody may find a solution for this? Is it may a bug? Are there workarounds for the cursor?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: when you use `if update(some_columns_name)` the `some_columns_name` part is between quotes?

Comment: No, as per sybase examples i found on the sybase website no quotes are needed. I figured out that it is not possible to use any variables in that update() function. Unfortunately it is also not possible to use dynamic sql because this update needs to run in a trigger and as i use exec() it is no longer in the trigger itself...any other ideas?!

Comment: Yes, the problem might be there. Are you familiar with dynamic sql?

Comment: Yes i am. I tried it and it did not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `update(@colname)` is something like `update('colname')` and needs to be `update(colname)`. In order to you achieve that, you need to **use Dynamic SQL**.

I've already saw [the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands56.htm) and it's possible to use:

> Dynamically executing Transact-SQL
>
> When used with the string or char_variable options, execute concatenates the supplied strings and variables to execute the
>   resulting Transact-SQL command. This form of the execute command may
>   be used in SQL batches, procedures, and triggers.

---

Check [this article](http://sybasease.blogspot.com/2005/05/dynamic-sql.html) for an example on how to use dynamic sql!

Comment: This is true but the problem is somewhere else: to run dynamic sql you need a exec() functionto execute the command. But this is in sub process somehow and therefore no longer in the trigger itself. then the problem is that this update() function is no long in the trigger and sybase ase gives me an alert...

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a problem to recreate the trigger every time the table is altered (columns added/dropped) you may just generate the body for your trigger with such query

```
select 
'if update('+c.name+')
   set @colname = '''+c.name+'''
'
from syscolumns c where id = object_id('my_table')
```